# Listed "last week" or "Past 7 days"

Tags: translation

I want to say *El listado de la última semana* (The new listing in the 7 past days) in English to make the translation in a website I´m doing, miami-partners.com/index.php#quick-search.

I try *Listed last week* but my boss say it doesn't sound good.
*Listed Past Week* should be fine or are there another way to say it?

Comment: How about *Latest Listings*, e.g. *Miami Beach Latest Listings*?

Comment: thanks @DamkerngT. but how can implicit the list is just the 7 past days, I mean the new listing in the 7 past days?

Comment: So, it's not just the latest updates, but specifically about the properties that were "newly listed" within the past seven days?

Comment: @DamkerngT. yes that's the idea

Comment: Then I guess that you can use the phrase *"This Week's Listings"*, as in *Miami Beach This Week's Listings* or *This Week's Listings in Miami Beach*. Because *This Week's Listings* is a little wordy, you can move it out to be the section's title. Your call. --PS. I think it's now good enough to be an answer, so I'll post it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use the phrase ***This Week's Listings***. For example, *Miami Beach This Week's Listings*, or *This Week's Listings in Miami Beach*.

Because the phrase *"This Week's Listings"* is a little wordy, I would like to suggest moving it out to be the section's title; so you can write only the place names under that title. But that's up to you.

Comment: I'll ask to my boss, but I think is better moving out to be the section title

Answer (score 2):

"This Week's Listings" is possible but ambiguous: It could mean listings for the most recent seven days, or it could mean listings for this calendar week. i.e. if it's the middle of the week, would a listing from last Friday be included or not?

"Listings for the past seven days" is unambiguous but a little wordy.

"Listings for the past week" would probably be understood to mean the past seven days.

If wordiness is an issue, you could always say something like "Current Listings" and then at the bottom of the page have a note to explain it, like "Current listings are listings originally posted or which have been updated within the last seven days". Moving the explanation to a footnote has the advantage that you can include details that would be out of place in a headline, like whether a 6-month old listing that was updated yesterday would be included, etc.